# Javascript | Min and Max Method To One DRY Method

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have a min a max function that are merely identical except one uses `Math.min` and the latter uses `Math.max`

```
// calculate min value
function getMinMetric(measurements, metric) {
  let value = null
  measurements.forEach(measurement => {
    if (measurement[metric]) {
      !value ? (value = measurement[metric]) : (value = Math.min(value, measurement[metric]))
    }
  })
  return value
}

// calculate max value
function getMaxMetric(measurements, metric) {
  let value = null
  measurements.forEach(measurement => {
    if (measurement[metric]) {
      !value ? (value = measurement[metric]) : (value = Math.max(value, measurement[metric]))
    }
  })
  return value
}
```

Either function will be returned based upon conditions such as:

```
function calculateStatsForMetric(stat, metric, measurements) {
  if (stat === 'min') return getMinMetric(measurements, metric)
  if (stat === 'max') return getMaxMetric(measurements, metric)
  *****
}
```

How could I combine the **min** and **max** function into one method for a DRY approach and so I don't end up with redundancy?

Further: Is this a good practice - Or in fact, I should aim for separate functions to return separate values (just as is now) so they can be independent and have separation of concerns?

Comment: Ugh, what's with the ternary operator that REALLY should be an `if`?

Comment: How so - cld you provide an example?

Comment: `!value ? (value = measurement[metric]) : (value = Math.min(value, measurement[metric]))` is just terrible. It doesn't need to be in one line and having to wrap the assignments in brackets should tip you off to that. At worse, it should have been `value = !value ? measurement[metric] : Math.min(value, measurement[metric])`.

Comment: Thank you VLAZ. I see. Living and learning here. More positivity and camaraderie rather than calling someone else's code terrible is also appreciated here at SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have `type` parameter in your function which will be `"min"` or `"max"`. And then you can call the `Math[type]` function using **Bracket Notation**. And also I am updated the ternary operator.

```
function getMetric(type,measurements, metric) {
  let value = null
  measurements.forEach(measurement => {
    if (measurement[metric]) {
      value = !value ? measurement[metric]) : Math[type](value, measurement[metric])
    }
  })
  return value
}
```

This is how you will call the function

```
getMetric('min',..., ...) //for min
getMetric('max',..., ...) //for max
```

Comment: Thank you Maheer Ali. so to call it on `calculateStatsForMetric()` I'd write: `if (stat === 'min') return geMetric(measurements, metric, Math.min)`. Is that right?

Comment: @Null isTrue no you need to pass `string` i.e `'min'` or `'max'` not function.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the function to apply as a parameter... and maybe refactor a bit the ternary operator to something like:

```
function getMetric(measurements, metric, whichFn) {
  let value = null
  measurements.forEach(measurement => {
    const currentValue = measurement[metric]
    if (currentValue) {
      value = value ? whichFn(value, currentValue) : currentValue
    }
  })
  return value
}
```

This way you can call it like:

```
getMetric(..., ..., Math.min)
```

Comment: I prefer this approach to passing in strings. It means that you can't accidentally type `getMetric(measurements, metric, "maxx")` or something. I'd swap the position of `whichFn` and put it first, so the signature becomes `getMetric(whichFn, measurements, metric)` now you can *derive* the original two functions via [partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application) `getMinMetric = getMetric.bind(null, Math.min)` and you still maintain a single piece of code for both of them.

Comment: Also, this way you can even pass down a function which isn't in the `Math` prototype, like a custom one.

Comment: I like what VLAZ said about preventing silent errors because of typos.

Comment: @0xc14m1z shouldn't `? currentValue` be `: currentValue`, right now there isn't an else on the ternary...

Comment: @NullisTrue you're right, that was a typo, I wrote the code directly in the answer :)

Comment: @0xc14m1z yep, that's another advantage of passing a function instead of only relying on `Math[funcName]`. Say, you decide to implement some new function based on this, like `getRandomMetric`. It probably doesn't make much sense, to be honest, but you can still just pass a `(a, b) => Math.random() < 0.5? a : b` and you'd get a non-deterministic metric out of this. Or maybe just something that always returns the same item because maybe you're not interested in others `(a, b) => a` - that would be a `getFirstMetric` and you can have a `getLastMetric` simply by using `(a, b) => b`.

Comment: @VLAZ you've shared great insights throughout this thread. I'd love to see an answer with your suggested more elegant approach. Your other comment about `Reduce` got me wondering how we can implement in such way.

Comment: @NullisTrue I am not sure I can add more than what the other answers already said. really, the only new information I've contributed is the partial application and `.reduce`/spread from [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55089044/3689450). And if you'd like a `.reduce` approach I think that one is pretty much what you want then the answer has all you need `measurements.map(/*...*/).filter(/*...*/).reduce((a, b) => Math.max(a, b))`. I'll see if I can write something that's substantially different to the other answers, though.

Answer (score 1):

I used `map` and `filter`.

```
function calculateStatsForMetric(stat, metric, measurements) {
  const arr = measurements.map(m => m[metric]).filter(v => !!v);
  Math[stat].apply(null, arr);
}
```

Comment: Also possible to use the spread operator `Math[stat](...arr)` or via `arr.reduce((a, b) => Math[stat](a, b))`. Although I think `.apply` is the most performant, if performance matters.